# display data ordered by characters descending - postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-order-by

I have this table:

```
create table Enrolment (
student integer,
course  varchar(5),
semester integer NOT NULL,
finalgrade char NOT NULL DEFAULT '-',
--constraints
foreign key (student) references Student(studentid) on delete cascade,
foreign key (course) references Course(courseid) on delete cascade,
primary key(student, course),
check (semester >= 1 AND semester <= 8),
check (finalgrade='F' OR finalgrade='P' OR finalgrade='G' OR finalgrade='E')
);
```

I want to see all enrollments ordered by the finalgrades descending, which are E(excellent), G(Good), P(Pass) and F(Fail).

```
create table Grade(
finalgrade char NOT NULL DEFAULT '-',
number integer,   -- E (corresponding to 1), G(2), P(3) and F(4)

foreign key (finalgrade) references Enrolment(finalgrade) on delete cascade,
primary key(finalgrade),

check (finalgrade='F' OR finalgrade='P' OR finalgrade='G' OR finalgrade='E')
);
```

then join tables to display the enrollments as the number in the second table. However, the constraint finalgrade of the first table is not unique so this solution doesn't work.
The data for the table is something like:

[image: table]

and I want to display the data as below - E grade will go first and then G then P and F:
[image: ordered table]

Comment: You've failed to include what you've attempted that "doesn't work". Please [edit] to include sample data, the output you want to obtain from that data, and the query you've used to try to obtain that result. It's difficult for us to provide "another solution" when you haven't provided the first one for us.

Comment: I have edited the post, hope you are more clear about my problem now. I have come up with the solution with Rémi's suggestion. Create another table grade (finalgrade,number) (E-1, G-2, P-3, F-4). and join these two table, order by grade.number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have your reference the wrong way. It should be the finalgrade of the Enrolment table that references the finalgrade of the Grade table, not the other way round like you did.